# posting wllpost to facebook without open facebook dialog

Tags: android, facebook

I am developing one app in that i have an edit-text and submit button when i enter some text and click on submit button then it will post to my Facebook account as wall post.
But i don't want to open Facebook wall-post dialog.is it possible? please help me if anybody knows..

Comment: Flagging this question as off-topic because it is unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple by  changing the code from github source method of facebook for posting feed  **showUpdateStreamFBDialog()** using below code

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
String facebookMsg = activity.getString(R.string.facebook_msg);
bundle.putString("message", facebookMsg);
facebook.request("/me/feed", bundle, "POST");
```

Comment: OK thanks for u r response but in which class i have to put this code.

Comment: have you downloaded api code with examples available from github repository?

Answer (score 0):

You need users to grant `publish_stream` permission to your application, once granted you may post to user's `feed` using Graph API